Why does my joblib.Parallel child worker never returns to the main loop when using Loky backend
I am using joblib.Parallel to run tasks using loky backend.
Sometimes the child workers hang, and after completing all the tasks, the control is never returned to the main loop.
I see this by logging in to the child process: I see it logs a message it has completed. However, the main loop that is calling Parallel(), never gets back its control.

macOS
Python 3.10
Joblib 1.4.2


Make sure your child process does not spawn its own child process, or otherwise manipulate processes, as this might cause the named behavior.

Try to avoid creating any processes in Loky child workers

Watch out for libraries like futureproof or anything that might internally use multiple processes and threads


What's the underlying interaction between different process pools and Python which causes the hang remains to be a mystery.
